# If $A$ has exactly $k$ nonzero eigenvalue and $A$ is normal, why is $\operatorname {rank}(A)=k$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A \in {M_n}$ has exactly $k$  nonzero eigenvalue and $A$ is normal, why is $\operatorname {rank}(A)=k$?

Comment: Even if $A$ isn't normal, the result holds.

Comment: @GitGud: If $A$ has all zero eigenvalues (take a Jordan block of size 2) then it may have non zero rank.

Comment: @GitGud $A$ must at least be diagonalizable for this to work

Comment: You're both right.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Actually, it is sufficient that the zero eigenvalue has no associated nontrivial Jordan block to have the nullity equal to  its algebraic/geometric multiplicity.

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is normal, it is unitarily diagonalisable.

If a matrix is diagonalisable, then we have
$\Lambda = V^{-1} A V$ for some $V$ with $\Lambda$ diagonal. It is easy to see that the rank of $\Lambda$ is $k$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** the number of zero eigenvalues of a matrix is the dimension of the kernel (nullspace) of a matrix.

Now, apply the rank-nullity theorem, noting that $A$ has $n$ eigenvalues in total.